# Access SQL query to sort based on NULL values and letter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like

```
  Ktype         EID        Basecode        
 ------         ----       ---------    
  sd             1001       S23   
  u                         M11     
  a              1003       R11    
  s              1004       M007     
  f                          M7  
  k              1006       W546     
  w              1005       N77    
  x                          A40
  b              1006       W546
```

How to get **Ktype** where **EID** is Null and **Basecode** Not starts with M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter clause will need to be:

```
where EID is null
and left(Basecode, 1) <> 'M'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select ktype From [table] where eid is null and basecode not LIKE 'M%'
```